# Amazon MWS - Throttling creates a big problem for me

Tags: amazon-web-services, throttling, amazon-mws

I have been working with a warehouse management system, which is integrated to Amazon MWS. My integration has been working for 2 years without a problem. Our bussiness grew bigger, so we started to send requests to Amazon MWS more frequently, which led me to a throttling problem. Unfortunately, I cannot reduce the number of requests that I send to Amazon MWS, this is how I keep orders and inventory correct.

My question is, is there any way that I can overcome this throttling issue by having a second API user or purchasing any other type of user, if exists.

Would you please give me an idea?

Comment: Can you give some examples of which operations are you talking about and what throttling quotas they have?